# Why isnt my last child li elemens padding not be removed?

Tags: html, css

My navigation anchor tag is the last child element of the navigation I tried removing the padding-left but it wont remove however when I try to add padding it adds it. Any thoughts about this?

```
<div class="main_nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="Logo/logo.png">
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Aboutus</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div

.main_nav{
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:90px;
    background-color:orange;
}
.logo{
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    padding-top:15px;
}
nav ul{
    float:right;
    padding-top:33px;
}
nav li{


    display:inline;
    padding-right:40px;
    background-color:yellow;

}
nav li:last-child a{
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code you actual want this:

```
nav li{
    display:inline;
    padding-right:40px; /* padding applied */
    background-color:yellow;

}
nav li:last-child { /* padding on last list item removed */
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

You haven't applied  padding to the anchor so it can't be removed with:

```
nav li:last-child a{
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

You stated:

> My navigation anchor tag is the last child element of the navigation.

Actually, it isn't (and it sort of is). In a list such as this *every* anchor link is the last child of the `li` as it's also the first and only child.

`nth-of` statements (which include `first` and `last` etc.) always refer the children of a parent element.

So the `li:last-child` will always be the last child of it's parent `ul`.